# RODBC::sqlQuery with temporary tables gives empty character vector though query works in SSMS and smaller queries work with same connection

Tags: sql, r, odbc, rodbc

I am trying to extract a dataframe from the results of an SQL query. I am using RODBC for this due to compatibility issues between PCs when using odbc and DBI. The connection is specified as such:

```
my_server="servername"
my_db = "databasename"

connect_rodbc <- RODBC::odbcDriverConnect(paste0("DRIVER={SQL Server};
                                 server=",my_server,";
                                 database=",my_db,";trusted_connection=true"))
```

All but one of the queries in my script work fine, but one that worked fine yesterday and works fine in SQL Server Management Studio is now returning an empty vector instead of the desired data frame and I don't know why.

The query is of the format:

```
dataset_needed <- RODBC::sqlQuery(connect_rodbc, "

IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Date') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Date
SELECT DISTINCT [Month]
INTO #Date
FROM [dbo].[TIMES_TABLE]
WHERE [Week End Date] BETWEEN  DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETDATE()) and GETDATE() 

IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Product') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Product
SELECT DISTINCT [Product Code], [Product Group]
INTO #Product
FROM [dbo].[PRODUCT_TABLE]
WHERE [Product Group] IN ('DVDs', 'CDs')

SELECT [Month],
SUM([Volume]) AS 'Volume'

  FROM [databasename].[dbo].[SALES_TABLE] r

  INNER JOIN #Date d ON r.[Month Code] = d.[Month Code]
  INNER JOIN #Product p on r.[Product Code] = p.[Product Code]  

  GROUP BY [Month]
                           ")
```

However:

```
test <- RODBC::sqlQuery(connect_rodbc, " SELECT TOP 10 * FROM SALES_TABLE")
```

works fine and returns a dataframe with 10 observations as expected, so the connection still works.

The original query takes around 2 minutes to run in SQL Sever Management Studio and appears to take around the same period to run in R, however it just results in an empty character vector

Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Removing the temp tables seems to have caused the query to work again, which is odd because I could have sworn it worked fine yesterday.

the new script I am using (not quite sure what's happened with the indentation) is:

```
dataset_needed <- RODBC::sqlQuery(connect_rodbc, "

SELECT [Month],
SUM([Volume]) AS 'Volume'

FROM [databasename].[dbo].[SALES_TABLE] r

  INNER JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT [Month]
FROM [dbo].[TIMES_TABLE]
WHERE [Week End Date] BETWEEN  DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETDATE()) and GETDATE()) as d 
ON r.[Month Code] = d.[Month Code]

  INNER JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT [Product Code]
FROM [dbo].[PRODUCT_TABLE]
WHERE [Product Group] IN ('DVDs', 'CDs')) as p
ON r.[Product Code] = p.[Product Code]

GROUP BY [Month]
                           ")
```